# yml file syntax highlighting with Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

How can I get proper syntax highlighting in yml files, such as users.yml with Sublime Text. As of now there is no highlighting, even erroneous things such as # symbols in string interpolation being treated as a commenting out hashtag.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/90) to completely replace the old YAML syntax highlighting definition with a new one. I haven't tested it yet, so I don't know if your particular issue has been addressed, but you can certainly [test it for yourself](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FichteForks/Packages/new_yaml_syntax/YAML/YAML.sublime-syntax) if you wish. Simply create a `YAML` folder in your `Packages` directory, and save the file I linked to in it as `YAML.sublime-syntax`. It should override the current syntax. All of this assumes, of course, that you've upgraded to build 3103 or are using the latest development build, otherwise the `.sublime-syntax` format won't be recognized by Sublime.